# Spark Streaming - Best way to Split Input Stream based on filter Param

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib

I currently try to create some kind of monitoring solution - some data is written to kafka and I read this data with Spark Streaming and process it.

For preprocessing the data for machine learning and anomaly detection I would like to split the stream based on some filter Parameters. So far I have learned that DStreams themselves cannot be split into several streams.

The problem I am mainly facing is that many algorithms(like KMeans) only take continues data and not discrete data like e.g. url or some other String.

My requirements would ideally be:

- Read data from kafka and generate a list of strings based on what I read
- Generate multiple streams based on that list of strings - (split stream, filter stream, or whatever is best practice)
- Use those streams to train different models for each Stream to get a baseline and afterwards compare everything that comes later against the baseline

I would be happy to get any suggestions how to approach my problem. I cannot imagine that this scenario is not covered in Spark - however until now I did not discover a working solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it should be sufficient to create derivate DStreams from the original, using filter and map:

```
val numericFeaturesDStream = originalDStream.filter(e => predicate(e)).map(e => extractFeatures(e))
val otherNumericFeaturesDStream = originalDStream.filter(e => predicate2(e)).map(e => extractOtherFeatures(e))
```

Note that these `filter` and `map` steps could be combined in one `collect` step (not to be confused with the parameterless RDD.collect that takes data to the driver!!!)

```
val featuresStream = originalDStream.transform(rdd => 
  rdd.collect{case (a,b,c,d,e) if c=="client" => Vectors.parse(a)}
)
streamingKMeans.trainOn(featuresStream)
```

We can also have a dynamic set of filtered DStreams held into some collection. Here we use a map that contains the key we used to filter:

```
originalDStream.cache() // important for performance when a DStream is branched out.
// filterKeys: Set[String] 
val dstreamByFilterKey = filterKeys.map(key => key -> originalDStream.filter(e => (getKey(e)==key)))
// do something with the different DStreams in this structure ...
```

These snippets are code examples to be completed with the actual logic.

Comment: And how would I go to do this for a dynamical List of Strings - e.g. a String[]? Can streams be stored in some kind of structure like an array or even better a map? As I have to access them later by some key or the other.

Comment: When I follow your instructions to create the set and then try to access the set in a foreach loop and call `forEachRDD` on the Streams in the Set i get the following exception: `java.io.NotSerializableException: Object of org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream is being serialized  possibly as a part of closure of an RDD operation. This is because  the DStream object is being referred to from within the closure.  Please rewrite the RDD operation inside this DStream to avoid this.  This has been enforced to avoid bloating of Spark tasks  with unnecessary objects` Any ideas?

Comment: This could be simple or complicated to solve :-). Could you create another question with the code you're using?