# Accessing Collection of DStreams

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to access a collection of filtered DStreams obtained like in the solution to this question: [Spark Streaming - Best way to Split Input Stream based on filter Param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44902723/spark-streaming-best-way-to-split-input-stream-based-on-filter-param)

I create the Collection as follows:

```
val statuCodes = Set("200","500", "404")
    spanTagStream.cache()
    val statusCodeStreams = statuCodes.map(key => key -> spanTagStream.filter(x => x._3.get("http.status_code").getOrElse("").asInstanceOf[String].equals(key)))
```

I try to access `statusCodeStreams` in the following way:

```
for(streamTuple <- statusCodeStreams){
      streamTuple._2.foreachRDD(rdd =>
  rdd.foreachPartition(
      partitionOfRecords =>
        {
            val props = new HashMap[String, Object]()
            props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaServers)
            props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
              "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
            props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
              "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
            val producer = new KafkaProducer[String,String](props)

            partitionOfRecords.foreach
            {
                 x=>{ 
                 /* Code Writing to Kafka using streamTuple._1 as the topic-String */
                 }
            }
      })
   )
}
```

When executing this I receive the following error:
java.io.NotSerializableException: `Object of org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream is being serialized possibly as a part of closure of an RDD operation. This is because the DStream object is being referred to from within the closure. Please rewrite the RDD operation inside this DStream to avoid this. This has been enforced to avoid bloating of Spark tasks with unnecessary objects`

How do I access the Streams to write to Kafka in a serializable way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the exception indicates, the `DStream` definition is being captured by the closure. 
A simple option is to declare this `DStream` transient:

```
@transient val spamTagStream = //KafkaUtils.create...
```

`@transient` flags certain objects to be removed from the Java serialization of the object graph of some object. The key of this scenario is that some `val` declared in the same scope as the `DStream` (`statusCodeStreams` in this case) is used within the closure. The actual reference of that `val` from within the closure is `outer.statusCodeStreams`, causing that the serialization process to "pull"  all context of `outer` into the closure. With `@transient` we mark the DStream (and also the StreamingContext)  declarations as non-serializable and we avoid the serialization issue.  Depending on the code structure (if it's all linear in one `main` function (bad practice, btw) it might be necessary to mark *ALL* DStream declarations + the StreamingContext instance as `@transient`.

If the only intent of the initial filtering is to 'route' the content to separate Kafka topics, it might be worth moving the filtering within the `foreachRDD`. That would make for a simpler program structure.

```
spamTagStream.foreachRDD{ rdd => 
    rdd.cache()
    statuCodes.map{code =>
        val matchingCodes = rdd.filter(...)
        matchingCodes.foreachPartition{write to kafka}
    }
    rdd.unpersist(true)
}
```

Comment: What is the advantage/disadvantage of using `@transient`? And does that have to be at initalization of the stream when I do transfomations until I reach finally the `spanTagStream`? Regarding the scenario: This was just some snipped of code I already had that would be capable of taking advantage of the Collection right away. Other use cases would be using the Stream as it is or written to a RDD over a certain amount of time to train some machine learning algorithm, or deliver data points to be compared against a trained model.

Comment: @LST added an explanation on `transient` to the question (too long for a comment, and I thought it would be of value for future reference in the question anyway) - The @transient mark needs to be at each DStream value assignment. A lot can be avoided by structuring the code in separate classes/objects and being careful with the serialization scope of closure.

Comment: Do you have a resoruce (maybe a git project you know or something like that) with good practice how to structure the application best to avoid the context issues and not needing to mark everything transient? I am still at the beginning and mainly learned from the tutorials on Spark home page and went from there. So I basically still do everything in the main method.

Comment: @LST I would advise you a book but would be blatant self-promotion :-)  Some guidelines to get you started: initialize the Streaming Context separately and pass it around as a parameter. Separate functions from dataflow: instead of a huge `foreachRDD{....}`, create a function `process(proc: RDD => Unit)` and use it as  `foreachRDD{process}`. In doing so, your dependencies become clear, b/c you will need to call e.g. `process(proc: RDD => Unit, filter:Set[String])` to pass the keys and you avoid closure creep.

Comment: Great advice with structuring - I moved the split to the RDD and structured the application into more method calls. Now everything works without a single `@transient`. I even managed to filter the RDDs, assign them to the Status set and then iterate through that set for the final processing.